# How to select a jcr:content node using a CQ dialog

Tags: components, aem

We are in situation where we need to allow the content authors to select a set of  jcr:content nodes which stores information about dam resources. Initially we were in an assumption that that the "pathfield" widget will help us to achieve the same.
But, later realized that the "pathfield" is not designed for the purpose. 
Is there any workaround to achieve the same?
Any pointers would be helpful, as it seems we are stuck.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use paragraphreference xtype for node selection.